# Making AngularJS service dynamic with input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to AngularJS development. I am trying to build a dynamic service, which updates the output with input elements. But, I am getting error every time.

What am I doing wrong in declaring the service functions.
Here is my html code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>A custom service with a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>
    <label>input a number</label>
    <input ng-init="m5=0" ng-model="m5"></input>
    <p>The hexadecimal value of {{m5}} is:</p>
    <h1>{{hex}}</h1>
</div>
```

my angularJS app is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(parseInt($scope.m5));
});
```

But my output of `{{hex}}` is not dynamic. It shows static value `NaN`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below-given service code:

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return Number(x).toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc($scope.m5);
});
```

Hope this will work fork for you.

But I prefer to use filter option for this. You can try filter like:
**AngulrJS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//Filter to conver input number into hexadecimal number 
app.filter('hexafy', function () {
  return function(x) {
    return Number(x).toString(16);
  };
});
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'hexafyFilter', function($scope, hexafyFilter) {
    $scope.m5 = 0;
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>A custom service with a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>
    <label>input a number</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="m5"></input>
    <p>The hexadecimal value of {{m5}} is:</p>
    <h1>{{ m5 | hexafy }}</h1>
</div>
```

Enjoy solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the [`ng-change` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>A custom service with a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>
    <label>input a number</label>
    <input ng-init="m5=0" ng-model="m5"
           ng-change="hex=toHex(m5)" />  ̶<̶/̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶>̶
    <p>The hexadecimal value of {{m5}} is:</p>
    <h1>{{hex}}</h1>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return parseInt(x).toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.toHex = hexafy.myFunc;
});
```

On each change of the input value, `$scope.hex` will be updated.

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).